# Can't call .join() on the values of some elements

Tags: jquery, arrays, join

I've got a variable `selectedTagNames` which I set thus:

```
var selectedTagNames = $(".js-tag-name:checked").map(function(){return $(this).val()});

selectedTagNames
=> ["song:age_suitability=11-13", "song:age_suitability=5-7"]
```

It **appears** to be an array.  I want to join the values into a single string with '||', but I can't:

```
var searchTerm = selectedTagNames.join('||')
=> VM7234:2 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
message:  "undefined is not a function"
stack: (...)get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }__proto__: Error
```

I can do it manually, rather than using the variable:

```
["song:age_suitability=11-13", "song:age_suitability=5-7"].join('||')
=> "song:age_suitability=11-13||song:age_suitability=5-7"
```

So, the value of that variable must be something different to the array that I use in the second example, even though it appears to be the same.  They both just return 'object' for `typeof()`.

I'm using jquery version 1.7.1.

Can anyone tell me 
a) what's going on here?
b) how to gather the values of the selected checkboxes into an array, so I can see how many there are, and join them together, avoiding whatever's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(selector).map()` returns an array-like object akin to what jQuery returns from a selector.

You need the static method instead:

```
$.map($('.js-tag-name:checked'), function(el) {
    return $(el).val();
});
```

Comment: ah..thanks!  Will mark this correct as soon as allowed :)

Answer (score 1):

`.map()` returns a jQuery collection, not an array. You can convert this to an array by calling `.get()` on the result.

```
var selectedTagNames = $(".js-tag-name:checked").map(function(){
    return $(this).val()
}).get();
```